# How to auto-forward emails from mail-in database to group lotus

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

It's possibile? forwarding from mail-in database email address to group lotus? Rule it's not a way in this case,  I have more ten 300 mail-in database to forward.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking if mail can be sent to a Lotus Notes group instead of being deposited into an existing mail-in database?  If so, the answer is "yes", just change the Internet address of the mail-in database and create a group whose internet address is what the mail-in used to be.

Comment: No, a need two different e-mail address, one on groups second in mail-in database. I need create forward/ or memo message from mail-in to e-mail group.

Comment: Just create the group in the NAB just like any other group.  There's an "Internet Address" field in the group document (just like there is for the mail-in database.)  Put the desired address there.

Comment: For what's? This give me nothing. Third address for what? If somebody send e-mail to mail-in address I would like send memo/ forward this message to group.

Comment: Is this for external mails, from the Internet? As Duston says, create a new group with as members the original Internet address of the mail-in database and the name of the group. You then have to remove the Internet address of the mail-in database.

Comment: I need this email adresata in mail-in db.

Comment: Ok, so now what I'm hearing you say is that you want a group (addressable from the Internet) and a mail-in database (also addressable from the internet) and when a piece of mail arrives in the mail-in database, a copy if it is also sent to a group, is that correct?  If that's the case then listen to what Richard Schwartz has to say.

Answer (score 0):

What I would normally do is create an agent in the mail-in database that is triggered after mail is delivered. Rather than forward the email, I would probably send out a notification email with a link to the actual email instead, but you could just as easily forward the email.

Comment: I was thinking about creating a universal agent with formula. Because each of the 300 address group accordingly address in the mail-in has DB manager mixedgroup permissions. It's possibile to create such universal agent?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but a "universal" agent would have to run on schedule instead of being triggered by mail delivery. It would be a more complex agent because it would have to open each mail-in database individually and it would have to keep track of which messages it had processed so that it would know to ignore them the next time. I would not do it this way. In theory, you could deploy an extension manager hook and a server task, written in C or Java, to do this, but that's complicated and very risky. I would not do that, either.

Comment: Assuming that all of your mail-in databases inherit from a template, you can just add the agent to the template and let the overnight design task update all the databases. I'm not sure if that will automatically enable the agent in all the databases, but you could write another agent that opens all the mail-in databases and uses the NotesAgent class to enable them using the IsEnabled property.

Comment: You can't access the acl from @formula, can you? it would be doable in LotusScript.

Comment: Yes, you can access the ACL from LotusScript, but I don't know what that has to do with this question.

Answer (score 0):

We do this with out support@ourdomain.com address. It arrives via a mail-in database record in the Domino Directory and then uses Mail Rules to forward messages to team members based on the subject or the sender. The Rules also folder the messages in the mail-in DB for reference later. Finally an agent comes along every month and removes everything older than 60 days.